# virtualization of Ubuntu 14.04 on macox using virtual box

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, virtualization, macosx, shortcut-keys

I have 2 main questions related to the virtualization.

First, after having installed ubuntu on VBox latest version on my macbook pro, the OS is working fine but display setting is stucked in 800x600. I have install vbox guest and extended but I still face the issue.

Second, the key : ~ {}[] ... and others are not mapped on the keyboard as it's a shortcuts done under MACOSX. Anyone know the procedure to have these characters working under Ubuntu when ubuntu is virtualized on a Macbook pro with a french keyboard ?